# A reference to a class member

Tags: c++

A reference to a class member is kind of an offset relative to the class. If I understood everything correctly. But why is 1 always output here?

```
#include <iostream>

struct user
{
  int id;
  double name;
  std::string last;
};


template<class V>
void kek(V b)
{
  std::cout << b << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  kek(&user::id);
  kek(&user::name);
  kek(&user::last);
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://godbolt.org/z/snxzzE9fG)

Comment: You have **pointers** to class members in this code, not _references_.  Are you trying to print the addresses?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`&foo::bar` is a *pointer*-to-member. There are no references-to-members.

`cout` can't print member pointers directly, the closest thing it can print is `bool`. Your pointer was converted to `bool`, and since it was non-zero, you got `true`.

If you want to get an offset from a pointer-to-member, you could try `std::bit_cast`ing it to `std::size_t`, but note that it's not guaranteed to work.

But if you just want an offset to a hardcoded member, use [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof). (thanks @TedLyngmo)

Comment: [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) may be worth mentioning

Comment: Hack trick: If you ever suspect you're getting `bool`s, you can confirm it by adding `std::boolapha` to the print command. If the output starts printing true and false, yousa gots unexpected `bool` conversion.